# By what margin did the House agree to the Senate amendment to the National Defense Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2014?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislative-process

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Defense_Authorization_Act_for_Fiscal_Year_2014), the "legislative history" box simply lists empty brackets for this House vote. [The congressional history itself](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/3304/actions) jumps straight from the Senate passing the amendment to the Senate agreeing to the House amendment to their amendment. How did the House pass the Senate amendment here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Defense_Authorization_Act_for_Fiscal_Year_2014) shows,

> House agreed to Senate amendment on December 12, 2013 () with further amendment

The actions for [H.R.3304](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-bill/3304/all-actions) for the House on that date refer to H. Res. 441.

[H.Res.441](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-resolution/441) - Providing for the concurrence by the House in the Senate amendments to H.R. 3304, with an amendment.

> Sets forth the rule for consideration of the Senate amendment to H.R. 3304 (National Defense Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2014).

H. Res. 441 passed 350-69.